# Hotel Management Database Design Problems

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get started with Web Development by trying to develop a Hotel Management System.

I am using MySQL 5.5.44 (Raspberry Pi Debian) and PHP PDOs for the Communication.

The Foreign Keys and Primary Keys are confusing the living hell out of me.

This is my DB Design (Graph created via DbVisualizer)

[image: HotelDB]

The Problems are:

I have an Option in the Members Area of the Website where a User can Cancel a Reservation. To do so I want to copy the cancelled Booking (Row in the Bookings Table) into the Cancellation Table and that works BUT after doing that i want to delete the cancelled Booking from Bookings Table. Now this is where my Dilemma starts. I cannot delete a Parent Row from the Bookings Table as the Booking ID in the Cancellation Table AND the Payments Table are connected via References (FK and PK).

I need the BookingID to be the PK as it is the only unique value in the entire System. A Customer might have a unique ID but he can have multiple Bookings and a PK must be unique in the Table. Multiple Bookings per Customer allow the same CustomerID to be present multiple times in the Table. But a BookingID is always unique, even if it is the same Customer. That is why i need to have the Booking ID.

How do i get this to work?

How can I keep BookingID as FK and PK in the Payments and Cancellation Tables but still get rid of the row in the Bookings Table?

Do i have to redesign the DB-Schema? If Yes, how would you do it?

Here are the `DESCRIBE`s of the Tables:

```
mysql> describe Bookings;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BookingID  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| Arrival    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Checkout   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RoomNumber | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| CustomerID | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Breakfast  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Nights     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Comment    | varchar(400) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BookType   | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| BookTime   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> describe Cancellations;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BookingID  | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| Arrival    | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Checkout   | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RoomNumber | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| CustomerID | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Breakfast  | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Nights     | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BookTime   | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CancelTime | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe Payments;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BookingID  | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| CustomerID | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Amount     | decimal(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Paid       | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PayTime    | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Invoice    | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Cancelled  | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I hope you guys can help a Beginner with his ambitious Project.

Thank You.

Comment: It seems a bit unnatural to have `Bookings` and `Cancellations` be two separate tables.  They contain the same data and represent the same thing.  Why separate them?  `Bookings` can simply have some kind of "status" column for which "cancelled" can be a valid state.  At most, if a `Cancellation` has extra data which isn't necessarily part of a `Booking` then give it a FK to `Bookings` and just store the extra data in it.  But don't copy the same data to multiple tables.  Manually keeping data synchronized is difficult and unnecessary.

Comment: i only wanted to have the "successful" Bookings in the Bookings Table. so i decided to seperate but i guess it was a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `cancellations` table completely, then add *one* of the following to the `bookings` table:

- `cancelled_at` timestamp nullable

  ```
  SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE cancelled_at IS NULL
  ```
- `is_cancelled` boolean default false

  ```
  SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE is_cancelled = 0
  ```

Comment: i didn't know booleans were possible... i will look into it. thanks

Comment: Yes, they're useful. Actually, since you'll also want to add the `cancel_time`, to that table, then you can just check if it's null and skip the Boolean.

Comment: ah ok! thanks! I'll just add CancelTime to Bookings and drop Cancellations!

Answer (score 3):

I would add a datetime cancelled field and include it in the booking table.   I'm sure you will want to keep track of when it was cancelled anyway.  Then having Boolean for it also would just be redundant.   It's really just a preference though,   some people think the Boolean values makes the SQL easier to read, but you would have to add constraints like having a cancelled reservation without a time stamp.

Comment: This is exactly what i did! I now have included a DATETIME Field called CancelTime to the Bookings Table. There is no Boolean Field and the Cancellations Table is history now. I check the CancelTime Field for NULL or not to verify the status. This seemed to be the easiest way!